# unable to make a button in html and css

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I start with the plain old way of making a button.

```
<div id="button">
<a href="#"><img src="button.png"></a>
</div>
```

After that whenever someone hovers mouse over the button the image should change but it doesn't, relavant css is

```
#button a:hover
{
    background-image: url('button2.png');
}
```

What is wrong here ? why isn't the image on the button being changed in response to mouse hovering.

Comment: Since when is that the 'plain old way of making a button'?

Comment: Yes, that's the plain old way of making a link. And it's not even all that plain. That doesn't mean you people have to downvote this.

Comment: oh come on guyz it was just an innocent phrase doesn't mean all of you have to pounce upon me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to do it this way you have to set a background image in the first place. The button you are building actually contains an actual `image` tag and not a background-image.

So possible work around: Set button.png as background-image for the button like this:

```
#button a
{
    background-image: url('button.png');
    height: 20px; /* set to actual height of button image */
    width: 200px; /* set to actual width of button image */
}
```

and then for the hover state do:

```
#button a:hover
{
    background-image: url('button2.png');
}
```

Don't forget to set height and width of the `#button a` (set it to the dimensions of the image) otherwise it won't show.

Comment: It's not the background that has to change at all.  You can't change an image's background.

Answer (score 1):

You've to change your code to:

```
<div id="button">
<a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

And, in CSS:

```
#button
{
    width: /* image width goes here */px;
    height: /* image heightgoes here */px;
}
#button a
{
    display:block;
    background-image: url('button.png');
    text-decoration:none;
}
#button a:hover
{
    background-image: url('button2.png');
}
```

---

For SEO purposes, you can also write a text inside the `<a>`, like:

```
<div id="button">
<a href="#">Title of the link</a>
</div>
```

Then hide it this way:

```
#button
{
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-999px;
    width: /* image width goes here */px;
    height: /* image heightgoes here */px;
}
```

OR this way:

```
#button
{
    overflow:hidden;
    width: /* image width goes here */px;
    height: /* image heightgoes here */px;
}
#button a
{
    ...other rules
    padding-left:/* a value higher than #button width */px;
}
```

Comment: Obviously he has to declare width and height on #button. Well, maybe it's not so obvious. I'll edit my answer.